# Compile custom directives

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to add dynamically a custom validation directive inside other custom directive. It works fine for system angular directive like "required", but not work for custom validate directive.

I have directive 'controlInput' with input, on which i dynamically add directive 'testValidation' (in real application in dependance from data of control-input).

```
<control-input control-data='var1'></control-input>
```

Directives:

```
app.directive('controlInput', function ($compile) {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    replace: true,
    template: '<div><input type="text" ng-model="var1"></div>',
    link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {

      var input = elem.find('input');
      input.attr('required', true);
      input.attr('test-validation', true);
      $compile(elem.contents())(scope);
    }
  };
});
app.directive('testValidation', function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function (scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
      ctrl.$parsers.unshift(function (value) {
        if (value) {
          var valid = value.match(/^test$/);
          ctrl.$setValidity('invalidTest', valid);
        }
        return valid ? value : undefined;
      });
    }
  };
});
```

Full example http://plnkr.co/edit/FylMfTugHrotEMSQyTfT?p=preview

In this example I also add simple input to be sure 'testValidation' directive is working.

Thanks for any answers!

Comment: The task is to build form by http request with description of form fields. Example json for field is {type: 'text', value: 'some@mail.com', name: 'email'}. Validation rules we can define by field 'name'

Comment: I think you must say require: 'ngModel' because in documentation it says : Defining your own validator can be done by defining your own directive which adds a custom validation function to the ngModel controller.

Comment: Yes, I done it:

`app.directive('testValidation', function () {

  return {

    restrict: 'A',

    require: 'ngModel',

    ...

}`

Or you mean something else?

Comment: I also noticed that if to remove input from DOM and insert it after $compile: `var el = $compile(input[0].outerHTML)(scope); input.remove(); el.insertAfter(elem.find('label'));`, custom  validation works. But this way not seems "angularway". :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT:**

I suggest you fix your original program by changing the template in the `controlInput` directive to:

```
template: '<div><input type="text" testdir required ng-model="var1"></div>'
```

I don't see why not do it as mentioned above, but another way would be to replace the input with a new compiled one:

```
input.replaceWith($compile(elem.html())(scope));
```

---

**NOTE:**

Change

```
 var valid = value.match(/^test$/);
```

To

```
 var valid = /^test$/.test(value);
```

From MDN:

[`String.prototype.match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match)

> Return value
>
> array An Array containing the matched results or null if there were no
>   matches.

[`RegExp.prototype.test()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) returns what you need, a boolean value.

Comment: Thanks, fixed it. But the problem is still remain. The directive works good if add it like that `<input test-validation="true" required ng-model="var2" />`, but not work if to apply `$compile(elem.contents())(scope);` after changing input's attribute.

Comment: nvm, I see now, on it

Comment: After adding custom validation directive in template it works, but the task is to do it dynamically.

Comment: @LubovVashpaova then do it the other way, replacing the input. Or create the whole input element dynamically.

Comment: Thank you, i done it: `input.replaceWith($compile(elem.html())(scope));`